# How to constrain HTML table to always have 100% height even if row contents are too large

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table, row-height

I am wanting to have a page with a fixed-height header and footer, and with the contents taking 100% of the remaining height.

I currently have the behavior I desire working in Chrome, but in Internet Explorer, the row will grow beyond the desired height, forcing the footer off of the page (as evidenced by the scrollbar on the page). I can't find a fix for the Internet Explorer problem for the life of me.

Here is the desired behavior (in Chrome), note the row does not expand to fit contents, and instead has the ability to scroll:

[image: Desired Behavior]

Here is the undesired behavior I am experiencing with Internet Explorer:

[image: Undesired Behavior]

Here is the approach I am taking:

```
<head>
   <style>
      body {
         margin: 0px;
         table-layout:fixed;
      }
      table {
         border-collapse:collapse;
      }
      table, tr, td {
         overflow:hidden;
         padding: 0px;
      }
   </style>
</head>

<body>
   <table style="width:100%; height:100%; top:0px; bottom:0px;">
      <!--HEADER-->
      <tr style="height:100px;">
         <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#ff0000; text-align:center;">
            <h1>Piano Festival</h1>
         </td>
      </tr>

      <!--CONTENTS-->
      <tr>
         <!--LEFT CONTENT PANE-->
         <td style="background-color:#ff00ff;">
            <div style="height:100%; overflow-y:scroll;">
            <form>
               <!--Form contents here-->
            </form>
            </div>
         </td>

         <!--RIGHT CONTENT PANE-->
         <td style="background-color:#00ffff; width:100%;">
         </td>
      </tr>

      <!--FOOTER-->
      <tr style="height:100px;">
         <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#00ff00";>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>
```

I'd prefer to avoid using any Javascript or CSS extensions. How can I work around this problem so that I get the same behavior in IE that I have in Chrome right now (scrollable contents instead of a growing row height)?

Comment: i would suggest doing this without using a table

Comment: This is not tabular data, so don't use tabular elements. If you want a tabular display, use CSS tables.

Comment: Here's a better approach: http://jsfiddle.net/juroto/HL6Ad/

Comment: @Dan Beaulieu, I had attempted doing this with divs first, which would have been my preferred approach. I had headers and footers working, as in the example you gave. But I ran into problems having two content columns filled with more content than there is room for, and having a scrollbar for each div to scroll within the divs. Is there any chance you could give me an example of how you would approach that?

Comment: added a jsFiddle for you to check out, let me know if this is what you were looking for

Comment: withdrew my answer, the other answer has it right

Answer (score 0):

I also highly recommend not using tables for this. Here is a refactored version using divs to get you started.

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <h1>Piano Festival</h1>
</div>

<div class="registration">
  ...lots of stuff....
</div>

<div class="main">
  Main section
</div>

<div class="footer">
  footer
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  margin: 0;
  background: darkgreen;
  height: 10%;
}

.registration {
  background: deeppink;
  width: 20%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 80%;
  float: left;
}

.main {
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer {
  background: blue;
  height: 10%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

[Here's a working demo.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNJmoW)

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for, and may solve my problem. I am going to spend a few minutes seeing if I can adapt it to have fixed-height header and footers instead of percentages, and make it so the right pane scrolls the same as the left. If I can fix those things, I'll accept this answer. :)

Comment: Once I switch to a fixed-height header and footer, I start running into the same issues I had encountered with using divs for this previously. I can't figure out how to size the content column divs to take up 100% of height except for what is used by the header and footer without there being issues with scrolling (part of the content divs being hidden under the footer or not displaying the bottom of the scroll bar)